# Display xml data into html

Tags: c#, .net, html, xml, xslt

I have a `xml` structure stored in `XDocument`.

I want to present as `html` document (or something similar)  , main idea that a web browser will be able to present it .

Does `XSLT` will right technology here ?

Is there some examples for how to do so ?

Thansk for help.

Comment: Check this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp And yes, to transform XML to HTML, XSLT is an excellent tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, XSLT is good for this.  I recently had to do this using the following code:

```
var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
xslt.Load(styleSheetFile, XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, new XmlUrlResolver());
xslt.Transform(xmlFile, outputFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT or LinqToXML. Many examples out there but you can start @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: How exactly this related to my question ?